# Protect Zero-Day Windows Exploit

Tags: ms-word, exploit

**How to protect**

**Zero-Day Windows Exploit**

***From word document***

Comment: This is not a programming question and, as such, is off-topic for Stack Overflow. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. Questions on general usage of Microsoft Word should be asked on an appropriate end-use forum (e.g., MS Answers).

Answer (score 0):

command -> Run as Administrator

1. `reg export HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ms-msdt filename`

Example: `reg export HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ms-msdt backupregistry`

2. `reg delete HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ms-msdt /f`

[How to run in command promt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ru0dJ.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).